# SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe shows error message 'Extraction Failed' in Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

I downloaded **SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe** and when i double click it, it starts extracting files, creates a folder of extracted file but doesn't complete the process. It displays an error Extraction Failed. I am using Windows 10, 64 bit OS.

I tried to extract files using cmd. Still same error is being displayed.

Comment: Maybe the download is corrupt. Try downloading it again.

Comment: I downloaded the file from Microsoft's official site, using the link : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Comment: Can there be any other possible reason for this error message?

Comment: Sometimes downloads get corrupted. It's such an easy thing to download again to eliminate download corruption. If it's still an issue you can move on and try other things.

Comment: Thanks. Issue solved. New download is working fine.